# Programmatically assigning Request.Files with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, http-post

I've got this really deep code I'm working with, which layers-upon-layers down uses **Request.Files** to access any files uploaded to a webform and does some processing on them. I don't really have the authority to modify the code at that level, so hence my problem.

My mission is to create a generic function that will accept a simple string-list of URL's and extract the data from them in order to perform the exact same processing that would be done if these files were uploaded via the webform. In order to do this without being allowed to modify the low-level code, I need to find a way to programmatically assign data to **Request.Files** from within my c# code so that when it get's called later on it's filled with my data.

My plan is to open a stream to the URL's to extract the file data, massage the data into some compatible object list, then hopefully do something like...

```
Request.Files = MyFileListFromURLs;
```

makes sense, ya? Except it's not seeming that easy. Anyone want to offer some guidance? perhaps there is a more correct way to do this, such as indirectly adding files to **Request.Files** by some other method?

Comment: Couldn't find any "usable" code out there that does what you want. But the hard way, you have to go through the rfc specs and implement it your self. However, for uploading a single file, you can refer to [this](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c)

Comment: and in gist what I am suggesting above is to make a c# program simulate a file upload...